# Designing authentication in android app through JWT API

Tags: java, android, authentication, jwt

### Background

We've developed a CMS in ASP.Net Core 2.2 a few years ago for company internal day-to-day stuff. It holds several hundreds of users and I'm considering adding an android app to it. The android app should mainly serve as a front end to existing logic in the ASP.Net controllers. The benefits of the Android app I expect to have are:

- Better UX
- User not having to type the password for each session (the ASP.Net page logs them out after 20 or 30 minutes of inactivity)
- Push notifications etc.

### Existing infrastructure

The CMS has already an API (JWT) which is used by several backend services and could easily be expanded to be used by every user through the android app. Unfortunately I'm not a professional developer in general and are quite new to Java especially, so please bare some patience with me as I'm asking for a general advise of how to handle the authentication in the android app (Java).

I read about [curity.id](https://curity.io/) and stuff like this, but IMO this would be kind of overkill to the whole project and would also require major changes to the already working fine ASP.Net website.

Now my question is whether the following would be an acceptable practice to do:

1. When the user opens the app for the first time, I ask him for his username and password (and optionally 2nd factor).
2. I make an http request to the API of the CMS in order to authenticate the user and get back the JWT token on successful authentication.
3. The JWT token gets stored in some way (e.g. SQLite DB) and is being used for subsequent requests being made to the API.
4. Since the the lifetime of the JWT token is also limited to a few hours and the goal is to keep the app running without prompting the user for his credentials all the time, I need to store the password also in some way in the app or a DB on the android device. This is actually the part which confuses me the most and I have no clue how I would store the password in a safe way, so it may be used again for authentication requests down the road. *(I'm aware that if the user uses 2nd factor there is no way around but to ask for the 2nd factor every time the token expires or to exclude the device or so, but this should not be within the scope of this question)*

So I would be grateful to get some judgements about this approach, if it is acceptable in general and what would be the best way to do about point #4.

Thanks a lot

Comment: "*Since the the lifetime of the JWT token is also limited to a few hours and the goal is to keep the app running without prompting the user for his credentials all the time, I need to store the password also in some way in the app or a DB on the android device.*" - Do not do that. If the system uses OAuth/OIDC, store the refresh token and use it to issue new access tokens. Storing the password in cleartext on the device is a risk.

Comment: 100% agree with @Turing85 use a refresh token. You shouldn't be save/storing a users password at all ever. There is no need and it only leads to a security risk

Comment: Thank you guys - I'll read about refresh tokens (wasn't aware such a thing exists).

Answer (score 1):

##### Do not store password

If store (and frequently send) passwords you defeat the entire purpose of a token. The token itself exists as a disposable means to substitute the primary authentication (yet is cryptographically sufficiently strong to replace it without reducing system security).

##### SIMPLE: Use a long token

Create a new authentication API (or add some parameters to the existing one) to enable the mobile APP to require a long-lasting token (for example 6 months). If you then store this token in the `SecureStorage` of the device you can be quite confident it can not be extracted from there.

*Remember that with this solution, you lose control over the authentication. This is not the best practice but is the easiest solution to adopt in the case of existing JWT infrastructures that use only one token.*

##### RECCOMENDED: Create a renew token system

Once you issued a token you cannot revoke it. Hence the main issue introduced by the 'long token' solution is that if a device gets lost it can not be de-authenticated. This can be solved by a renew token:

- You create an authentication API that after the confirmed authentication it creates a unique `sessionId`, stores it in the DB, and issues a special token that contains the `sessionId` among other information. This is called the **renew token**. This special token can be used only for the **exchange API**
- You then create an exchange API, that expects a **renew token** in exchange for a normal **token** (that can have the same properties your current token has). This API will always check if the `sessionId` present in the renew token is still marked as active in the DB otherwise will not issue the normal token.

*This approach allows you to have very long expiring tokens but still have control to remotely log out the app (by masking the `sessionId` as deactivated in the DB) and even monitor how frequently the app is used.*